# PowerShell - New-Object : A Postional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'system.object[]'

Tags: powershell

I am having issues with the code written below. What the code is supposed to do is grab a list of predefined users and then attempt to test 3 passwords against the users' accounts. (Full code has been placed below in the answers) I keep receiving errors within the code as stated above in the title. Could any one help me figure this out? I always come here looking for answers as you guys are the best! Today I am unable to figure this out.

```
              $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential Argumentlist $account, $entry
              foreach ($account in $accountfile){
                   try {
                         get-aduser “username” -credential $cred
                         $array += New-Object psobject -property @{'Account'=$account;'Password'=$entry}
                   }
                    catch { Write-Host "There was an issue"}
               }
        }
        $count++#increase counter
  }
  $newpass=$newpass[3..$newpass.count] #subtract the first 3 entries from the $newpass array
  $count= 0 #reset counter to zero
```

Comment: I see a couple of issues but just running the line with `New-Object` didn't create an issue for me. So you that exact code above and you get the error?

Comment: Yes, Matt pointed out to me that I was missing a '-' on the arguments list. After I added that, I was prompted to continuously type in my username and password for the users in the list it reads from. Once it completes it outputs a new error ""New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count:"2""

Comment: What type of `$account` and `$entry`?

Comment: They should be strings. The users and the passwords are read in by get-content and stored within $account and $entry.

***Sorry for the comment above. I meant to say Mike, not Matt pointed out the "-" in Arguments.***

Comment: @Kr0n1kK1ll3r I assumed as much

Comment: For `PSCredential`, second parameter should be `SecureString` not `String`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Where would I set the second parameter to be SecureString?

Answer (score 2):

You missed the - on ArgumentList.

```
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Argumentlist $account, $entry
```

Comment: Good find, thank you. Now I am receiving "New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count:"2"
It is also asking me for each user in the list to type in my username and password to run. Is there a way to automate that?

Comment: `$secure = ConvertTo-SecureString $entry -AsPlainText -Force`